# SSRS integrating .Net MVC, my reportviewer webcontrol always link to jquery.min.js 3.1.1 version only

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, reporting-services, ssrs-2012, reportviewerformvc

I am working on .Net MVC application with SSRS report integration
Am using latest version of Report Viewer controls for WebForms (150.1427.0). and ReportviewerforMVC nuget pacakges.
Everything is working as expected.. but  in the security scan result we found report pages are fefering to old version of Jquery and JqueryUI ..... as shown below

```
<script src="/reservered.reportviewerwebcontrol.axd?OpType=Resource&amp;Version=15.0.1449.0;Name=Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.Scripts.Jquery.min.js" Type="text/javascript"></script>

Reportviewer page is displaying jquery v3.1.1 js file where it should use latest jquery, Need help on this 
As per the documentation and Release Notes for Report Viewer controls for WebForms and WinForms of SSRS, since the version 150.1357.0  its has been Updated JQuery to version 3.3.1.

why is this displaying 3.1.1 jquery and how do I make it use latest jquery version.

Can some one help me on this
```

Comment: Can someone please look into my issue ..

Comment: Hello.. any solution ?